# Laravel eloquent UNION query with extra column addSelect() not working

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, orm, eloquent

```
$first = DB::table('users')
        ->select("id","full_name")
        **->addSelect("user_table AS tableN")**
        ->where("full_name", "LIKE", "%a%");

    $users = DB::table("medical_specialties")
        ->select("id","name")
        **->addSelect("medical_speciality_table As tableN")**
        ->where("NAME", "LIKE", "%a%")
        ->union($first)
        ->toSql();
```

This is laravel Eloquent query , where addSelect method should create new column in result set "Type" which will include some text ie table name but it gives this error 
[image]

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: Laravel 4.2 because it is a lagacy project and cannot be updated

Comment: What's the result of the `->toSql()` call?

Comment: You can't select different column names from different tables with `UNION`. In your case, you select `full_name` in your first part of the query and `name` in your second. Rename one of them to match the other.